# How do I install xorg-macros?

Tags: apt, xorg, autoconf

I'm trying to build xf86-input-libinput from source to apply a patch. When I follow the recipe given [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1278266/686407) at the step `autoreconf -vif` I get an error saying:

```
configure.ac:41: error: must install xorg-macros 1.8 or later before running autoconf/autogen
```

I've tried `sudo apt-get install xorg-macros` to no avail (unable to find source package). How can I install `xorg-macros`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An `xorg-macros.pc` pkg-config file appears to be provided by package [xutils-dev](https://packages.debian.org/buster/xutils-dev)

> This package also contains xorg-macros.m4, a set of macros used in configure scripts of X.Org packages.

Answer (score 0):

To follow on from the answer from steeldriver, on AlmaLinux 8.6 (and possibly on other RHEL based distributions) the `xorg-x11-util-macros` package provides the `xorg-macros.pc` file:

```
[mr_halfword@haswell-alma libpciaccess]$ yum provides "*/xorg-macros.pc"
Last metadata expiration check: 0:04:29 ago on Sat 30 Jul 2022 16:26:40 BST.
xorg-x11-util-macros-1.19.2-1.el8.noarch : X.Org X11 Autotools macros
Repo        : powertools
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/share/pkgconfig/xorg-macros.pc
```